# Spring integration test & set field to controller

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, jhipster, spring-test

I am trying to create my first integration test, inspiring myself from the jhipster project.

In my setup, i use that kind of code:

```
    CampaignController campaignController = new CampaignController();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(campaignController, "securityService", securityService);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(campaignController, "campaignService", campaignService);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(campaignController, "messageService", messageService);

    MockMvc restMvcCampaignController = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(campaignController).setMessageConverters(TestUtil.getCustomJsonMessageConverter()).build();
    RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(restMvcCampaignController);
```

Services are autowired classes.
I would like to know if "ReflectionTestUtils.setField" is a good practice or if there is anything else better I could use ?

Thank you

Comment: Don't use field injection :). Create a constructor for your `CampaingController` which takes the 3 services as arguments. Make the fields in your controller `final` and `@Autowire` the constructor. That will make your code cleaner, better OO ([you shouldn't do field injection](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/)) and saves you from those ugly reflection hooks.

Comment: @M.Deinum it sounds a bit funny to recommend a link where an author claims to replace field injection with constructor injection when a big side of the replies state that field injection is fine and also in use for years. In my sense it's OK to use either or. Tools like `ReflectionTestUtils` and `Whitebox` are well tested. Also, often a requirement for TDD is that a test has to fail first before it goes green.

Comment: Field injection isn't a best practice, the fact that something is being used doesn't mean it is good... It basically violates a core principle of OO and that is that you shouldn't be able to construct an object in an invalid state. Which is exactly what you do with field injection.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice. Instead of making it impossible to set the dependencies (other then by reflection), inject the dependencies via a constructor. For example

```
@Controller
public class Controller {
    private CampaignService campaignService;

    @Autowired
    public Controller(CampaignService campaignService, MessageService messageService) {
         //bind fields
    }
}
```

Now you can instantiate the controller easily from the test.